# Select records from table1 depending on table2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to build a project where you can like other people's pictures, and when the other person likes your picture too, you have a match. Like the Tinder app if you know.

Now, I fetch 1 photo like so:

```
SELECT id, picture_path, profile_picture, username 
       FROM tusers 
       WHERE profile_picture IS NOT NULL
             AND settings LIKE '1,%' 
             AND sex = :sex
             AND last_visit BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY AND CURDATE()
             AND dob BETWEEN :dob - INTERVAL 5 YEAR AND :dob2 + INTERVAL 5 YEAR
LIMIT 1
```

However, if you've already LIKED or PASSED someone's photo, I don't want to show it to you again. I am not sure how to do this part yet (right now, I have alreadyLiked() and alreadyPassed() functions and I am only doing a header("Location") redirect if they return true, but that will fail when you have liked/passed all the photos).

I have another table with these columns: `id`, `user1_id`, `user2_id`, `liked`, `passed`, `matched`

When you like or pass a picture, a 1 is inserted in the corresponding column.

`user1_id` is your ID. `user2_id` is the other person's ID.

Knowing the above information, what kind of query (or logic) would you use to make sure that you only show the right people (that you haven't liked or passed already) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have 2 tables

**usr**

```
id  username
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

**liked**

```
id  user1   user2   liked
1    1       4          1
2    1       3          1
```

assuming your id is 1 , from table liked it seems you have liked c,d . since 1(a) is your own id you need only b as output, your query goes as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM usr
WHERE id NOT 
IN (

SELECT user2
FROM liked
WHERE user1 =1
)
and id!=1
```

**assuming `1` will come from session**

Comment: Which column would you recommend most on indexing (in the table 'liked') ?

Comment: I was thinking `user1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql join to get data from one table based on the another

In the upper case you can have join on the first tables id with the other tables user1_id, user2_id putting where clause on the liked, passed, matched

[To know more about mysql joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Try this as join is much better than a inner query suggested by ersumit `$loggedINuser_id='2';//take from session $sql="SELECT tu.id, tu.picture_path, tu.profile_picture, tu.username FROM tusers tu LEFT JOIN secondtable st ON tu.id=st.user2_id WHERE tu.profile_picture IS NOT NULL AND tu.settings LIKE '1,%' AND tu.sex = :sex AND tu.last_visit BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 21 DAY AND CURDATE() AND tu.dob BETWEEN :dob - INTERVAL 5 YEAR AND :dob2 + INTERVAL 5 YEAR AND st.user1_id != '".$loggedINuser_id."' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: I'm having trouble making up my query with the join. I'm sure I'll understand it soon enough, but are you able to come up with a quick example for my case?

Comment: As we don't know beforehand the ID's of the other people (represented by the user2_id column), I am not sure if JOIN works.

Comment: @DanyP Can you please show the table structure and what exactly you want to display and to the first user or to the second user once i got your idea writing a query will take only five minutes

Comment: The table structure of table 1 is basically in the big query in my post. The other table structure is id, user1_id, user2_id, liked, passed, matched. The query should not fetch people that I have already liked or passed. So if user1_id (23) liked user2_id (25), then the big query should not fetch the user with id 25.

Comment: @Veerendra: to format blocks of code, you can use the "code" button in the toolbar, or use four spaces of indent for each line. It makes it much easier to read `:-)`. The backticks are for small snippets of code, inline in text.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for the suggestion but i already used ctrl+K to format code but most of it was string only so may be it looks like this